# Unable to change the button value next to another button - Javascript - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to once press a random value on from the 25 given and change the value of the button next to it?

http://jsfiddle.net/ehcfqm22/

```
$(document).on('click', '#table input',function () {
    var value1 = "";
    value1 = $(this).val();
});
```

I'm able to get the current button value but that's about it.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to change. Please clearly describe your aim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the value of the next button e.g. adding

```
$(this).parent("td").next("td").find("input").val(value1);
```

to your function.

I've added it in your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33wv3ueg/)

For the previous button, it's

```
$(this).parent("td").prev("td").find("input").val(value1);
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '#table input', function () {
    var value1 = "";
    value1 = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent("td").next("td").find("input").val(value1);
});
for (a = 1; a <= 25; a++) {
    var makeTable = false
    if (!makeTable) {
        $('#table').append('<table>');
    }
    $('#table').append('<tr>');
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        $('#table').append('<td>' + '<input type="button" class="numVa" value="' + a + '">' + '</td>');
        a++;
    }
    a--;
    $('#table').append('</tr>');
}
$('#table').append('</table>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

**Update:** For the previous unclear requirement that not only the value of the next and/or previous button should be changed, but also the values of the buttons above and below, adjusted [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuv07t09/)

Adjustment as follows: For getting the index/number of the cell and row of the clicked button, using `index()`:

```
var bCell = $(this).parent("td");
var bRow = bCell.parent("tr");
var bCellNr = bCell.parent("tr").children().index(bCell);
var bRowNr = $("#table tr").index(bRow);
```

And then setting the values for the buttons with the same index in the following `(bRowNr + 1)` and previous `(bRowNr - 1)` rows :

```
$("#table tr:eq(" + (bRowNr + 1) + ") td:eq(" + bCellNr + " ), 
  #table tr:eq(" + (bRowNr - 1) + ") td:eq(" + bCellNr + " )")
  .find("input").val(value1);
```

in case the button in the bottom row should change the value in case a button in the first row is clicked or

```
$("#table tr:eq(" + (bRowNr + 1) + ") td:eq(" + bCellNr + " )")
   .find("input").val(value1);

if(bRowNr > 0)
{
  $("#table tr:eq(" + (bRowNr - 1) + ") td:eq(" + bCellNr + " )")
    .find("input").val(value1);
}
```

in case clicking  a button in the first row shouldn't change last row button values ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aee51jp7/). for this version).

As the previous table contained wrong markup (empty rows, several empty tables), the cleaned up code with the second variety as snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#table input', function () {
    var value1 = "";
    value1 = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent("td").prev("td").find("input").val(value1);
    $(this).parent("td").next("td").find("input").val(value1);
    var bCell = $(this).parent("td");
    var bRow = bCell.parent("tr");
    var bCellNr = bCell.parent("tr").children().index(bCell);
    var bRowNr = $("#table tr").index(bRow);
    $("#table tr:eq(" + (bRowNr + 1) + ") td:eq(" + bCellNr + " )").find("input").val(value1);
    if (bRowNr > 0) {
        $("#table tr:eq(" + (bRowNr - 1) + ") td:eq(" + bCellNr + " )").find("input").val(value1);
    }
});
for (a = 1; a <= 25; a++) {
    $tr = $("<tr>");
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        $tr.append('<td>' + '<input type="button" class="numVa" value="' + a + '">' + '</td>');
        a++;
    }
    a--;
    $('#table').append($tr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! to also change the button above it(e.g. 20) will i have to do it manually?

Comment: @Ace Glad that helped you. As you only wrote "the button next to it" it wasn't clear you mean multiple buttons at once. Can you update in your question what you want to achieve? E.g. should click on 8 change the values of all surrounding buttons (3,7,9,12,13)?

Comment: Because I thought it would have the same principle :x sorry, but yeah that's what i was wanted :)

Comment: @Ace It's a similar principle and not too complicated. prev() and next() already take care about the values left and right, for the possible values in the row above and below it can be adjusted. Just noticed that the table that you generate is wrong, it contains several tables and empty  rows as you add the tds directly to the table :) Will update in some minutes.

Comment: I've tried  $(this).parent("td").parent("tr").next("tr").child("td").find("input").val(value1);

Comment: @Ace Updated the answer. Problem was that in your original code this wouldn't have worked as e.g. all the `tr` are empty and the `td` were added directly to the table (and there were several tables inside the table). I've cleaned that up so the markup is now valid.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, pushing a button should make the text of the button next to it change, if so, this will work

```js
$(document).on('click', '#table input',function () {
  $(this).next("input[type='button']").val('i\'ve been changed by the '+$(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"><input type="button" value="first button"/><input type="button" value="second button"/><input type="button" value="third button"/><div>
```